# Reformat pivot table output for table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pivot table called `pivot` that I have created using:

```
pivot = MonthyData.pivot_table(index=['year'],columns=MonthyData['month'], values=['total_pos'], aggfunc='sum')
pivot = pivot.rename(columns=lambda x: look_up.get(f'{str(x).zfill(2)}', x))
pivotdf = pivot.reset_index()
pivotdf=pivotdf.fillna(0).astype(int)
pivotdf=pivotdf.replace(0, '-')
```

and looks like:

```
       year total_pos                                                   \
month                 Jan     Feb     Mar      Apr     May     Jun     Jul   
0      2005             -       -       -        -       -       -       -   
1      2006        176119  346592  158928    73999  -45773  115140  163590   
2      2007        -96906    9942   -8859   161790  -62723   70319   45462
```

I need to format the table for a report.  How can I remove the `year` and `total_pos` and `month` index column so the data-frame looks like this?

```
                Jan     Feb     Mar      Apr     May     Jun     Jul   
 2005             -       -       -        -       -       -       -   
 2006        176119  346592  158928    73999  -45773  115140  163590   
 2007        -96906    9942   -8859   161790  -62723   70319   45462
```

Comment: change `values = ['total_pos']` to `values='total_pos'` in `pivot_table`.?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

As @QuangHoang, pointed out in the comments, it helps if you provide the name of the columns because you are applying `.pivot()` onto the data.frame, so it can look for the column to pivot. Once you have that, you almost have the table you need, just need to remove the names of the index:

```
MonthyData = pd.DataFrame({'year':np.random.choice([2005,2006,2007],100),
                           'month':np.random.choice(['Jan','Feb','Mar'],100),
                           'total_pos':np.random.uniform(0,1,100)})
MonthyData['month'] = pd.Categorical(MonthyData['month'],categories=['Jan','Feb','Mar'])


pivotdf = MonthyData.pivot_table(index='year',columns='month', values='total_pos', aggfunc='sum')
pivotdf.columns.name = None
pivotdf.index.name=None
pivotdf

             Jan         Feb         Mar
2005    7.039743    4.314391    3.827450
2006    6.679975    6.091983    3.706505
2007    8.847631    4.412842    3.931816
```